# Twitter Search API - Is it possible to return tweets that aren't truncated?

Tags: twitter

I am searching for tweets using the Twitter search API, however when a tweet has a line break or two, or is simply too long, the tweet is truncated and ends with '...' (often, but not always followed by a t.co link).

Is it possible to return a tweet's full text from the search API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently Twitter changed how it displays tweets and how they're represented in the API - see https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets

You need to add `?tweet_mode=extended` to the end of your query.  That will get you back the data you want.